# category order and subcategories WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have just started with WP and am slowly building my pages. I have now come across two questions relating to categories that I cannot find an answer for.
Can I change the order in which the category and the subcategory are displayed? They seem to be alphanumerical in order but I would like this order:
`category,subcategory` and not `subcategory,category`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_categories()` to create arrays and then sort it whatever you like with PHP.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories